# I'm been invaded by a Weretortoise

Tags: dwarf-fortress

[image]

I'm being invaded by a Weretortoise. I have no idea what a Weretortoise is, or how to prepare for one. I can't seem to find anyone on it in the DF wiki.

Im fairly new to DF and this is my first major threat. What should I do?

Comment: BE AFRAID, for this beast craves blood, and will stop at nothing until it's appetite is sated. This is the beast you tell stories of to make others fear the night, and rightly so... It is fear incarnate.

Comment: Or, you can catch it and add it to your PokeDex.

Comment: For the record, you can find more info about werebeasts on the wiki here: http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Werebeast

Comment: Or your first wooden bolt will pierce it's brain and you can have tortoise munchies for the whole year!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't let him in the fortress. Eventually, he will turn back into a human. Most of the time, the human will then just leave.

Comment: doesn't it say it is a tortoise that is turned into a human? so its natural form is a tortiouse, no?

Comment: @antony.trupe "A huge tortoise twisted into a humanoid form". A werewolf is a wolf in a humanoid form, meaning it looks like a wolf, but stands upright, and has arms like a man's, a torso like a man's (even opposable thumbs!!). So no, in this case it's a man, transformed into a giant, bloodthirsty tortoise.

Comment: oh, I always thought werewolves were humans in (part)wolf form.

Comment: I didnt have my draw bridge set up, so he was coming in anyways. Luckily the first thing I did was pause and did a TON of reading. I set up a burrow, put out a civlian alert and got everyone inside. I forgot to move the grazers outside so I lost 2 horses, but not too bad. After that he started coming in and I got EXTREMELY lucky: The first Dwarf caravan was in, and it came with a bunch of military dwarfs who did all the hard work. Cowering in feat: 1, Weretortoise: 0